# Increasing Optimization Level g++

Tags: c++, optimization, g++, cygwin

I'm trying to compile a relatively simple c++ program using cygwin and g++. I can compile it using the following command:

`g++ -o main main.cpp -lgmpxx -lgmp`

(note: the last two reflect the inclusion of the gmp libraries).

I'd like to increase the level of optimization that this is compiled with. I thought that I could just change this command line to:

`g++ -o3 main main.cpp -lgmpxx -lgmp`

but this totally blows up. I get about two full screens of error messages.

How can I increase the optimization here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That should be `-O3`, not `-o3`.  Otherwise you're telling g++ to put the compiled executable into a file named `3`, and you're feeding it `main`, your previously-compiled executable, as *input*.  It's probably trying to interpret that as source code, hence the errors.

Answer (score 10):

Options are case sensitive: the `-o` option allows you to specify the name of the output file, `-O` sets the amount of optimisation, so you want:

```
g++ -O3 -o main main.cpp -lgmpxx -lgmp
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't realize that there was any case sensitivity.